# positioning the raphael paper object

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

i'm trying to learn all i can about the paper object in raphael. i've exhausted the raphael docs on the subject but one thing's got me (by the nads) how on earth do you position the paper object?

i've tried using the setViewBox method but the x and y do not respond. is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
```

The first parameter is x, second is y.
Source: First line of code on [their home page](http://raphaeljs.com/)

To move the page itself after it has been created, use js to set the 'top' and/or 'left' style properties of the dom element

Comment: the problem with this is that it does not allow you to set the parent of the 'paper' ...

Answer (score 4):

Raphael can be positioned in the DOM via CSS. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #derp { position: absolute; width:200px; height:100px; }
</style>
```

`<div id="derp">Loading...</div>`

Then, to instantiate it:

`var my_paper = Raphael("derp", 200, 100 );`

You can mix and match DOM elements with Raphael. For an example, see http://jsfiddle.net/NQtU5/

Comment: it seems wrong to set any props on the div element, once it has been wrapped by raphael ...